# Sort command not working as intended on numbers

Tags: command-line, sort

Here's my list.txt:

```
a    100
b    300
A    50
e    75
1    10
```

I ran the command below:

```
sort -k2,2 list.txt
```

This is what I got:

```
1    10
a    100
b    300
A    50
e    75
```

I am trying to only sort the second column. According to Wikipedia, my command above should give me the result below.

```
a 10
b 50
A 75
e 100
1 300
```

Am I missing anything?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, `sort` sorts character-by-character in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), based on the current locale's [collation sequence](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html). So in your example `100` sorts after `10` but before `50` because `1` always sorts before `5`.

To sort in numerical order, you need to add the `n` specifier

```
   -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

e.g.

```
$ sort -k2,2n list.txt
1   10
A   50
e   75  
a   100 
b   300
```

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by explaining the term "lexically". Please see my [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290102/344239)